# Microsoft Graph API auhetication for service apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We are developing a web application using [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/), where the signed in user can, Export all the calendar events to a third party calendar Application. After this initial export, we need to keep the exported data in sync with calendar changes via service app (a scheduled task running on server). This need to be a multi tenant application, as people from different organizations should be able to use this service.

Right now we did the authentication using OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect as described in [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant). Later we understood that the access token we get using this method cannot be used in the service app without user interaction. Considering our scenario what is the best way to achieve this?

I have read about [App-only authorization method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx) to do this. If we use this authentication method, the app need to be consented by a tenant administrator and the these applications are quite powerful in terms of what data they can access in the Office 365 organization. Considering we are developing a product used by different organizations, will it be feasible to use this method?

Answer (score 1):

To use the client credentials OAuth2.0 flow (aka "App-only" or service account access depending on who's documentation you're reading) the admin for each tenancy will need to specify which scopes your daemon process can have for users in their tenancy.  The end users can't give these scoping rights to your code themselves (as far as I know at least).

One thing to watch out for is that currently Graph API doesn't allow you to mess about with calendars that are attached to Office 365 Groups if you're using the client credentials flow.  This is a pain for us, so we've [raised it as an issue that needs fixing in the Office 365 feedback system.](http://office365.uservoice.com/forums/286611-office-365-groups/suggestions/11591322-allow-daemons-using-graph-api-client-credential-fl) if that's an issue for you or anyone else, please throw a few votes at it so that it gets more attention at Microsoft. :-)